How can self-attention be used to combine representations from long text?
The paper "How to Fine-Tune BERT for Text Classification?" discusses using self-attention to combine the representations of a long input text that has been broken into chunks (section 5.3.1).

The input text is firstly divided into k = L/510 fractions, which is fed into BERT to obtain the representation of the k text fractions. The representation of each fraction is the hidden state of the [CLS] tokens of the last layer. Then we use mean pooling, max pooling and self-attention to combine the representations of all the fractions.

However, the paper does not go into detail on how this is actually done. Could anyone please explain how this is accomplished or provide examples that go into greater detail? I'm looking to implement this in Python alongside code that uses the Hugging Face transformers package.

Their source code is public.
